# Warning when using a command as label argument for a list?

Tags: macros, lists, warnings

I'm having difficulties with a list where the label is defined as a command. Below is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\newcommand{\myLabel}{1)}

\newenvironment{myList}%
  {%
    \begin{enumerate}[\myLabel]
  }
  {%
    \end{enumerate}
  }



\begin{document}

\begin{myList}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
\end{myList}

\end{document}
```

When I compile this, I get the following warning

```
LaTeX Warning: The counter will not be printed.
         The label is: \myLabel  on input line 19.
```

and the generated list only has `1, 1, 1` as labels instead of `1, 2, 3`.

Any idea how to work around this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to expand `\myLabel` before using it

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\newcommand\myLabel{1)}

\newenvironment{myList}%
  {\expandafter\enumerate\expandafter[\myLabel]}
  {\endenumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{myList}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
\end{myList}

\end{document}
```